# Why is Azure Functions creating V1 Storage Accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

We're usually using Azure Functions + SPA (e.g. Angular) for a lot of different projects. That means technically we can host the Functions and the web frontend inside the same Azure Storage Account, as long as it is v2 to support static website hosting.

However, whenever I create an Azure Function App and let it auto-create the storage account it creates a v1 account. Is there any reason why v1 would be better for Functions than v2?

From Microsofts docs:

> General-purpose v2 accounts: Basic storage account type for blobs, files, queues, and tables. Recommended for most scenarios using Azure Storage.

> General-purpose v1 accounts: Legacy account type for blobs, files, queues, and tables. Use general-purpose v2 accounts instead when possible.

I haven't seen any issues running Azure Functions in a v2 Storage Account so I'm wondering why v1 is still the default option?

Comment: We have been using V2 Storage for Functions for quite some time at least :)

Comment: same, that's why I don't get it defaulting to v1

Comment: Hi, @Thomas,  Would you mind accept my answer for others to refer if it help?

Comment: I would like to keep this open for a bit longer since you're answer is plausible but does not include an official statement or a definitive reason for v1 over v2.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Storage V1 has lower transaction costs than V2. Azure Functions, especially durable functions heavily use storage blobs and tables as synchronisation database generating extremely high bills for storage account. therefore recommendation is to use storage V1 due to lower costs.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#legacy-storage-account-types

> General-purpose v1 accounts may not have the latest features or the
> lowest per-gigabyte pricing. Consider using it for these scenarios:
>
> - Your applications require the Azure classic deployment model.
> - **Your applications are transaction-intensive or use significant geo-replication bandwidth, but don’t require large capacity. In this
>   case, a general-purpose v1 account may be the most economical
>   choice.**
> - You use a version of the Azure Storage REST API that is earlier than February 14, 2014, or a client library with a version lower than 4.x,
>   and you can’t upgrade your application.
> - You're selecting a storage account to use as a cache for Azure Site Recovery. Because Site Recovery is transaction-intensive, a
>   general-purpose v1 account may be more cost-effective. For more
>   information, see Support matrix for Azure VM disaster recovery between
>   Azure regions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the General-purpose v1 storage account is the legacy version of Azure storage account and can basically meet most of the needs, so it was the best choice for setting it with Azure Function by default.

As we can see from [the official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-upgrade?tabs=azure-portal):

> 1. General-purpose v2 storage accounts incorporate all of the functionality of general-purpose v1 and Blob storage accounts.
> 2. Upgrading a general-purpose v1 or Blob storage account to general-purpose v2 is **permanent** and **cannot be undone**.

For better user experience, I think it's not a problem to set GPv1 storage account by default. If you need more functionality about Storage, you could consider upgrade to GPv2.